# Getting Blur Strokes while drawing in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, drawing, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I am working on Drawing in iOS, I have my code working, drawing is working fine, Now I have implemented undo and redo functions, **but what is happening is that, suppose I draw two lines and then press undo button, then the first line drawn is getting Blur,** and I am not understanding why its happening, below is my undo code.

-

```
(void)redrawLine
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    NSDictionary *lineInfo = [lineArray lastObject];
    curImage = (UIImage*)[lineInfo valueForKey:@"IMAGE"];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:self.bounds];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}



-(void)undoButtonClicked
{
    if([lineArray count]>0){
        NSMutableArray *_line=[lineArray lastObject];
        [bufferArray addObject:[_line copy]];
        [lineArray removeLastObject];
        drawStep = UNDO;
        [self redrawLine];
    }

}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    switch (drawStep) {
        case DRAW:
        {
            [curImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
            CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2); 
            CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 

            [self.layer renderInContext:context];
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
            CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y); 
            CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapButt);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
            CGContextSetAlpha(context, self.lineAlpha);
            CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES);
            CGContextStrokePath(context);            
            [super drawRect:rect];  

        }        
        case UNDO:
        {
            [curImage drawInRect:self.bounds];   
            break;
        }
}
```

Below is the image of what is happening when undo button is pressed

First Image is before undobutton is clicked and second Image is after undobutton is clicked

[image: Before Undo Button clicked]
[image: After Undo Button Clicked]

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` is specifying the size of the bitmap in points (i.e. 320x480 for full-screen), but on a device with a retina display, you'd need one that's the size of the screen in pixels (i.e. 640x960).

You should be able to call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` with `scale` set to 0.0. From the docs:

> The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.

Comment: Hi Martin thanks a lot, it solved the issue, how to determine scale factor? And this issue was also on ipod touch(which is without retina display).

Comment: Thanks, man, I have same unwanted blur, but this solution fixes it!

Comment: huge help! didn't suspect this! Thank You.